# Can't run the emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I made a mistake as I close the PC by force ,and when I open the PC again and open the project I found the files are scattered and error on all xml :

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

and can't run the emulator as shown here

[image]

I tried to open the project in another PC but the problem is still ongoing.
I also can't create new project

[image]

what should I do to fix this problem ?

Comment: try invalidate cache/restart, file -> invalidate cache/restart -> click invalidate and restart. 
 It work for me

Comment: not worked :( @mochamad-taufik-hidayat

Comment: Refresh gradle.

Comment: how ? there are a lot of gradle in project files @lukas-knuth

Comment: On the Right side it says "Gradle", open that window-pane and klick the refresh icon.